# What is the main difference between NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:delegate and sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I was wondering about the difference with the two NSURLConnection protocols or methods (or whatever they are actually called).

I'm very new to Objective-C programming and I'm trying to create an iOS app which loads data from a website. I noticed on the tutorials I've watched/read that when they use the connectionWithRequest, they have other methods which appeared to me as methods that are needed for the connectionWithRequest to work properly. One tutorial is [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/ios-tutorial-part-1-creating-a-web-service/). These methods are:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
```

Just to name two. And regarding this, I have another question: are these methods automatically called when the NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:delegate is called or used?

What exactly are the difference between the two NSURLConnection protocols that I've mentioned? Which is better to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is in different type of callback:

- Method `-connectionWithRequest:delegate:` uses delegation and you have to implement `didReceiveResponse`, `didReceiveData` and other to make it useful. This is **more complicated**, but allows you to handle security authentications, progress tracking and similar things.
- Method `+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` uses block completion, which is **much easier** in comparison to delegation. It handles receiving response and appending body data and simply gives you the result.

*Footnote:* iOS 7 introduced completely new URL loading mechanism of `NSURLSessions` which can be used instead of `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a good link for you to understand NSURLConnection and it's delegate methods.

http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/